# Sorting in the DOM with adjacent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sorting, plugins

I have the the following DOM structure which I want to sort according to the `data-created` attribute.

```
<a id="comment-34" href="#"/>
<li data-created="12342342" />

<a id="comment-35" href="#"/>
<li data-created="89342342" />

<a id="comment-36" href="#"/> 
<li data-created="45363342" />
```

I *CANNOT* (for various reasons) wrap the `<a>` and `<li>` in an outer `<div>`. I want to do javascript sorting. All the jQuery sorting plugins can do the sorting if I just had the `<li>`. E.g. using the tinysort jQuery plugin ( http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/ ) I can do

```
$('li').tsort({order:'desc', attr:'data-created'});
```

However what happens after the sort is that `<a>` are no longer associated with their original siblings. I also evaluated https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/sortElements/ but it may suffer from the same problem.

Any way to do this? Again, I cannot wrap the `<a>` and `<li>` in an outer `<div>`. I also don't want to dynamically wrap a `<div>` so that I can use tsort.

Any clean solutions :-) ?

Comment: FYI, that's not valid HTML. It's impossible to have `li` and `a` elements as siblings.

Comment: To my knowledge this is valid HTML. The `<a>` before the `<li>` for instance can be used as an anchor.

Comment: The only elements that can contain LI elements are OL and UL, and neither can contain A elements.

Comment: @ikegami On investigation I find that you are correct. A HTML validator also complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
var elms = [];
$('a').each(function() { //create the array of a and li
    var pair = {
        aTag: $(this),
        liTag: $(this).next("li")
    };
    elms.push(pair);
});
$("a, li").detach(); //detach them from the dom
elms.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.liTag.data("created") < b.liTag.data("created"); //sort based upon the created data
});

$.each(elms , function(){
    $("ul").append(this.aTag).append(this.liTag); //push them back to the dom.
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/xWmQW/).**

Comment: I like this solution. Its clean. Kudos for also using detach() vs remove(). Thanks.

Comment: heh. did we have the exact same idea at the same minute? good thought on detach().

Answer (score 1):

You can't really have `<li>` and `<a>` elements as siblings in the first place. A list item must be inside a list (`<ol>`,`<ul>`), where other elements are not allowed.

Ignoring that, you can simply grab each pair, remove from the DOM, reorder, then put them back. It's quite straight-forward. Example:

```
var items = [];
$('#sortme a').each(function(){

  // grab the element and its next sibling
  var self = $(this)
    , next = self.next('div');

  items.push([
    self.remove().get(0),
    next.remove().get(0)
  ]);
});

items.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1].getAttribute('data-created') > b[1].getAttribute('data-created');
});

$.each(items, function(){
  $('#sortme').append(this[0], this[1]);
});
```

Test here: http://jsbin.com/okajo4/edit

**Edit:** a simpler version :)

```
var sorted = $('#sortme');

sorted.find('div')
  .sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).data('created') > $(b).data('created');
  })
  .each(function(){
    $(this).prev('a').andSelf().appendTo(sorted);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `a` elements inside their respective list items. Then you ought to be able to use the sort you mentioned.

Even if having the elements as siblings is valid, it still strikes me as bad form.